# Make a grid to be closer to the top of the page - XAML

Tags: xaml, position, margin

I have the following XAML:

```
<Grid    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12" Width="260" Height="32" PlaceholderText="Confirm Password"  BorderBrush="#FF755CB0" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.9" x:Name="ConfirmPassword"/>
            <Button Content="Sign-Up" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="12" Grid.Row="1"  Width="260" Height="50" Background="#FF235085" BorderBrush="#FF6749AC" BorderThickness="1" Foreground="White" Opacity="0.9" RequestedTheme="Light" Click="Register_Click"/>
        </Grid>
```

Right now the grid is at the center of the screen, I wabt it to be a little bit higher, I can do it with `margin`, but I don't want any propery with `pixel` in my page. Is there any other wahy to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get your grid slightly above the centre without using Margins would be to put it in another Grid.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1.2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12" Width="260" Height="32" PlaceholderText="Confirm Password"  BorderBrush="#FF755CB0" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.9" x:Name="ConfirmPassword"/>
        <Button Content="Sign-Up" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="12" Grid.Row="1"  Width="260" Height="50" Background="#FF235085" BorderBrush="#FF6749AC" BorderThickness="1" Foreground="White" Opacity="0.9" RequestedTheme="Light" Click="Register_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Note the second RowDefinition

```
<RowDefinition Height="1.2*"/>
```

This means the second row will take slightly more of the available space than the first row and you can adjust to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks. But now it's not even clode to be in the center, the content is at the bottom of the page...

Comment: It shouldnt be. start a test app and just put in the code above to see how it works then adjust for your app as its probably to do with other Grids, panels etc in your code

Comment: If I want it to be closet to the top I have to change the <RowDefinition Height="1.2*"/>
 to <RowDefinition Height="8*"/> I don't know why. In my page I hae only that grid, and have no other XAML element

Comment: Yes that will mean the second row is 8 x bigger than the first.